# Webscraping past a show more button that extends the page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from Elle.com under a search term. I noticed when I click the button, it sends a request that updates the &page=2 in the url. However, the following code just gets me a lot of duplicate entries. I need help finding a way to set a start point for each iteration of the loop (I think). Any ideas?

```
import requests,nltk,pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def get_hits(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html')
    body = []
    for p in soup.find_all('p',{'class':'body-text'}):
        sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(p.text)
        result1 = [s for s in sentences if 'kim' in s]
        body.append(result1)
        result2 = [s for s in sentences if 'kanye' in s]
        body.append(result2)
        body = [a for a in body if a!=[]]
    if body == []:
        body.append("no hits")
        
    return body

titles =[]
key_hits = []
urls = []

counter = 1
for i in range(1,10):
    url = f'https://www.elle.com/search/?page={i}&q=kanye'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html')
    groups = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'simple-item grid-simple-item'})
    for j in range(len(groups)):
        urls.append('https://www.elle.com'+ groups[j].find('a')['href'])
        titles.append(groups[j].find('div',{'class':'simple-item-title item-title'}).text)
        key_hits.append(get_hits('https://www.elle.com'+ groups[j].find('a')['href']))
        if (counter == 100):
            break
        counter+=1

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Title':titles,
    'Body':key_hits,
    'Links':urls
})
data.head()
```

Let me know if there's something I don't understand that I probably should. Just a marketing researcher trying to learn powerful tools here.

Answer (score 0):

To get pagination working on the sige, you can use their infinite-scroll API URL (this example will print `9*42` titles):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


api_url = "https://www.elle.com/ajax/infiniteload/"
params = {
    "id": "search",
    "class": "CoreModels\\search\\TagQueryModel",
    "viewset": "search",
    "trackingId": "search-results",
    "trackingLabel": "kanye",
    "params": '{"input":"kanye","page_size":"42"}',
    "page": "1",
    "cachebuster": "undefined",
}

all_titles = set()

for page in range(1, 10):
    params["page"] = page

    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(api_url, params=params).content, "html.parser"
    )
    for title in soup.select(".item-title"):
        print(title.text)
        all_titles.add(title.text)

print()
print("Unique titles:", len(all_titles))  # <-- 9 * 42 = 378
```

Prints:

```
...

Kim Kardashian and Kanye West Respond to Those Divorce Rumors
People Are Noticing Something Fishy About Taylor Swift's Response to Kim Kardashian
Kim Kardashian Just Went on an Intense Twitter Rant Defending Kanye West
Trump Is Finally Able to Secure a Meeting With a Kim
Kim Kardashian West is Modeling Yeezy on the Street Again
Aziz Ansari's Willing to Model Kanye's Clothes

Unique titles: 378
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, load more pagination is generating from api calls plain html response and each page link/url is relative url and convert it into absolute url using urljoin method and I make pagination in api_urls.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

api_urls = ["https://www.elle.com/ajax/infiniteload/?id=search&class=CoreModels%5Csearch%5CTagQueryModel&viewset=search&trackingId=search-results&trackingLabel=kanye&params=%7B%22input%22%3A%22kanye%22%2C%22page_size%22%3A%2242%22%7D&page="+str(x)+"&cachebuster=undefined" for x in range(1,4)]
Base_url = "https://store.steampowered.com"
for url in api_urls:
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content,"lxml")
    cards = soup.select("div.simple-item.grid-simple-item")

    for card in cards:
        title = card.select_one("div.simple-item-title.item-title")
        p = card.select_one("a")
        l=p['href']
        abs_link=urljoin(Base_url,l)
        print("Title:" + title.text +  " Links: " + abs_link)

    print("-" * 80)
```

Output:

```
Title:Inside Kim Kardashian and Kanye West’s Current Relationship Amid Dinner Sighting Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37833256/kim-kardashian-kanye-west-reconciled/
Title:Kim Kardashian And Ex Kanye West Left For SNL Together Amid Reports of Reconciliation Efforts Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37919434/kim-kardashian-kanye-west-leave-for-snl-together-reconciliation/
Title:Kim Kardashian Wore a Purple Catsuit for Dinner With Kanye West Amid Reports She's Open to Reconciling Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37822625/kim-kardashian-kanye-west-nobu-dinner-september-2021/
Title:How Kim Kardashian Really Feels About Kanye West Saying He ‘Wants Her Back’ Now Links: 
https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37463258/kim-kardashian-kanye-west-reconciliation-feelings-september-2021/
Title:Why Irina Shayk and Kanye West Called Off Their Two-Month Romance Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37366860/why-irina-shayk-kanye-west-broke-up-august-2021/
Title:Kim Kardashian and Kanye West Reportedly Are ‘Working on Rebuilding’ Relationship and May Call Off Divorce Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37421190/kim-kardashian-kanye-west-repairing-relationship-divorce-august-2021/
Title:What Kim Kardashian and Kanye West's ‘Donda’ Wedding Moment Really Means for Their Relationship Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37415557/kim-kardashian-kanye-west-donda-wedding-moment-explained/
Title:What Kim Kardashian and Kanye West's Relationship Is Like Now: ‘The Tension Has Subsided’ Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37383301/kim-kardashian-kanye-west-relationship-details-august-2021/
Title:How Kim Kardashian and Kanye West’s Relationship as Co-Parents Has Evolved Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37250155/kim-kardashian-kanye-west-co-parents/Title:Kim Kardashian Went Out in a Giant Shaggy Coat and a Black Wrap Top for Dinner in NYC Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37882897/kim-kardashian-shaggy-coat-black-outfit-nyc-dinner/
Title:Kim Kardashian Wore Two Insane, Winter-Ready Outfits in One Warm NYC Day Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37906750/kim-kardashian-overdressed-fall-outfits-october-2021/
Title:Kim Kardashian Dressed Like a Superhero for Justin Bieber's 2021 Met Gala After Party Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37593656/kim-kardashian-superhero-outfit-met-gala-after-party-2021/
Title:Kim Kardashian Killed It In Her Debut as a Saturday Night Live Host Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37918950/kim-kardashian-saturday-night-live-best-sketches/
Title:Kim Kardashian Has Been Working ‘20 Hours a Day’ For Her Appearance On SNL Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37915962/kim-kardashian-saturday-night-live-preperation/
Title:Why Taylor Swift and Joe Alwyn Skipped the 2021 Met Gala Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37446411/why-taylor-swift-joe-alwyn-skipped-met-gala-2021/      
Title:Kim Kardashian Says North West Still Wants to Be an Only Child Five Years Into Having Siblings Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37620539/kim-kardashian-north-west-only-child-comment-september-2021/
Title:How Kim Kardashian's Incognito 2021 Met Gala Glam Came Together Links: https://store.s
teampowered.com/beauty/makeup-skin-care/a37584576/kim-kardashians-incognito-2021-met-gala-beauty-breakdown/
Title:Kim Kardashian Completely Covered Her Face and Everything in a Black Balenciaga Look at the 2021 Met Gala Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37578520/kim-kardashian-faceless-outfit-met-gala-2021/
Title:How Kim Kardashian Feels About Kanye West Singing About Their Divorce and ‘Losing My Family’ on Donda Album Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37113130/kim-kardashian-kanye-west-divorce-song-donda-album-feelings/
Title:Kanye West Teases New Song In Beats By Dre Commercial Starring Sha'Carri Richardson Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37090223/kanye-west-teases-new-song-in-beats-by-dre-commercial-starring-shacarri-richardson/
Title:Inside Kim Kardashian and Kanye West's Relationship Amid His Irina Shayk Romance Links: https://store.steampowered.com/culture/celebrities/a37077662/kim-kardashian-kanye-west-relationship-irina-shayk-romance-july-2021/
```

and ... so on